# Unity - Importing a sound to play on keypress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code, but i am not getting any sort of errors and a lot of googling hasn't come up with any answers

What am i doing wrong?

```
public class FirstPage : MonoBehaviour {

public AudioSource mySound;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mySound = Resources.Load("05 - Listen to the Man_[plixid.com]") as AudioSource;
}

void Update () {
if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)){
        mySound.Play();

    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because you're trying to load an [AudioSource](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) rather than an [AudioClip](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html).

The correct way is to load an audio clip, assign it to an audio source and then play the clip using [AudioSource.Play()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html)

```
public class FirstPage : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource mySound;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        var audioClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("05 - Listen to the Man_[plixid.com]");  //Load the AudioClip from the Resources Folder
        mySound.clip = audioClip;  //Assign it as AudioSource's clip
    }

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)){
            mySound.Play();
        }  //Also, I removed the extra semi-colon you had here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is "05 - Listen to the Man_[plixid.com]" an asset within your project? If not I believe that's why this won't work. I'm pretty sure [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) is just for loading your existing assets into RAM, so that they're ready when you need them.

I did a bit of looking around, and you might find [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/importing-audio-files-at-runtime.140088/) useful, as well as [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.GetAudioClip.html) from the Unity reference docs.

Here's a sample of JS from there that should do the trick. Hopefully you can translate into C# easily enough if that's what you prefer :)

```
var www = new WWW ("file://" + Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.LastIndexOf ("/")) + "/result.wav");

AudioClip myAudioClip= www.audioClip;
while (!myAudioClip.isReadyToPlay)
yield return www;
gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().audio.clip = myAudioClip;

audio.Play ();
```